# Sending NSDate in JSON format in the body of NSMutableRequest

Tags: ios, json, api, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to do an API call to a webservice in which you have to send a date in the body of the request in order to get the desired data. I have done API calls,  but not where you send any JSON in the body of the request. My best guess is that you'd have to use and NSMutableURLRequest. See my attempt below. When i do this i keep getting error from the Webservice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
//1. Create a NSURL 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:apiString];

//2. Create NSMutableRequest.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *json = @"{requestDate: '2015-09-01'}";

   [request setHTTPBody:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//3. get data
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {



    if (data != nil) {


        [self processData:data];

    }else{

        NSLog(@"%@," connectionError.localdescription) 


    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would work, but it's hard-coded and error-prone.

You'd be much better off setting up a dictionary and then using `NSJSONSerialization` (which has a method `dataWithJSONObject` that takes a "JSON object" {an object that can be converted to JSON} and returns well-formed JSON data).

So your code for creating the JSON data would look like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter() //create a date formatter.
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateToSend)
let dictionary = ["requestDate": dateString];
var error: NSError
let theJSONData NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
  dictionary,
  options: .PrettyPrinted,
  error: &error
)
```

Alternatively you could use AlamoFire, a 3rd party library (available on Github) that would do both the networking and the JSON serialization for you.